# Cierre de sesión automática por inactividad de usuario en un periodo x de tiempo

Tags: javascript, java, web, session, servlets

Tengo el siguiente problema con el cierre de sesión automática, como se puede ver tengo un contador que va de segundo en segundo y cuando llega a un determinado tiempo entra en las condicionales que se lo da, pero cuando estoy en otra pestaña del navegador u otra aplicación el tiempo no corre igual y cuando se suspende la pc  se detiene el contador y ya no sigue con su flujo respectivo.

```
var warning=120;
var timeout=300;

var current = 0;
var timeOutActive = true;
 
function getSecs() {
    if (timeOutActive) {
        if (window.parent.document.getElementById('loading')) {
            if (window.parent.document.getElementById('loading').style.display === "none") {
                console.log(current);
                current = current + 1;
                if (current === warning) {
                    //popUpTimeOut(path + "/SimcoWeb/temp/timeOutAdvertencia1.jsp");
                    $(window.parent.document.getElementById("warning")).modal('show');
                    var timeInactivad = timeout - warning;
                    mostrarTimeIna(true, timeInactivad);
                }
                if (current === timeout - 10) {
                    //popUpTimeOut(path + "/SimcoWeb/temp/timeOutAdvertencia2.jsp");
                    $(window.parent.document.getElementById('warning')).modal('hide');
                    $(window.parent.document.getElementById("warning2")).modal('show');
                }
                if (current === timeout) {
                    cerrarSessionTimeOut();
                    //window.parent.location.replace(path + "/SimcoWeb/temp/timeOutCerrarSesion.jsp");
                    //window.top.location.href = path + "/SimcoWeb/temp/timeOutCerrarSesion.jsp";
                }
                window.setTimeout('getSecs()', 1000);
            } else {
                window.setTimeout('getSecs()', 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}

getSecs();

function cerrarSessionTimeOut()
{
    showLoading();
    $.ajax({
        url: path + "/usuarioFachada",
        type: "POST",
        data: {function: "cerrarSessionTimeOut"},
        dataType: "html",
        error: function (e) {
            //alert("Ocurrio un error: " + e);
            hideLoading();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            window.top.location.href = path + "/SimcoWeb/temp/timeOutCerrarSesion.jsp";
            hideLoading();            
        }
    });
}


function setSecsIna(currenteTime) {
    current = currenteTime;
}
```

Comment: No dices que esperas que ocurra cuando eso sucede, pero suponiendo que quieres que eso actue y no continue al volver, aparte del setTimeout le pondria algun tipo de verificacion de fecha/hora adicional por si acaso al regresar del letargo intenta continuar el setTimeout

Comment: Lo que espero que suceda es que cuando llegue a 120 segundos me salga el primer modal de advertencia por inactividad del usuario, luego a los siguientes 290 segundos el segundo modal y por ultimo la pantalla de cierre de sesión, cosa que no sucede cuando estoy en otra pestaña del navegador o utilizando alguna otra aplicación o en todo caso cuando se suspende la pc. cuando suceden esas situaciones así pasen horas mi sesión sigue activo!!!!!!!!!!